# boost::process How to correctly read process std::cout and std::cerr and preserve order

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

I'm starting a process through `boost::process`. The process uses `std::cout` and `std::cerr` to output some information. I need to retrieve those information. At some point, I want to be able to store those outputs preserving order and severity (output from `cout` or `cerr`).

But I could not achieve that considering the way `boost::process` redirects the outputs. I could only redirect `std::cout` to a specific ipstream and `std::cerr` to another. Then, when reading them, I can't preserve the order.

Here is a MCVE isolating teh problem:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void doReadOutput( boost::process::ipstream* is, boost::process::ipstream* err, std::ostream* out )
{
    std::string line;
    
    if ( std::getline( *is, line ) ) 
        *out << "cout: " << line << std::endl;
    if ( std::getline( *err, line ) ) 
        *out << "cerr: " << line << std::endl;
}

void readOutput( boost::process::ipstream* is, boost::process::ipstream* err, std::ostream* out, std::atomic_bool* continueFlag )
{
    std::string line;
    while ( *continueFlag )
    {
        doReadOutput( is, err, out );
    }

    // get last outputs that may remain in buffers
    doReadOutput( is, err, out );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if ( argc == 1 )
    {
        // run this same program with "foo" as parameter, to enter "else" statement below from a different process
        try
        {
            boost::process::ipstream is_stream, err_stream;
            std::stringstream merged_output;
            std::atomic_bool continueFlag = true;

            boost::process::child child( argv[0],
                                         std::vector<std::string>{ "foo" },
                                         boost::process::std_out > is_stream,
                                         boost::process::std_err > err_stream );

            boost::thread thrd( boost::bind( readOutput, &is_stream, &err_stream, &merged_output, &continueFlag ) );

            child.wait();

            continueFlag = false;

            thrd.join();

            std::cout << "Program output was:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << merged_output.str();
        }
        catch ( const boost::process::process_error& err )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << err.code() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...)                                                                                                                                      // @NOCOVERAGE
        {                                                     
            std::cerr << "Unknown error" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // program invoked through boost::process by "if" statement above

        std::cerr << "Error1" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello World1" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error2" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error3" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error4" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error5" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello World2" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error6" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello World3" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this program (Compiled with Visual Studio 2019 under Windows 10), it outputs:

```
Program output was:
cout: Hello World1
cerr: Error1
cout: Hello World2
cerr: Error2
cout: Hello World3
cerr: Error3
cerr: Error4
cerr: Error5
cerr: Error6
```

While I want:

```
Program output was:
cerr: Error1
cout: Hello World1
cerr: Error2
cerr: Error3
cerr: Error4
cerr: Error5
cout: Hello World2
cerr: Error6
cout: Hello World3
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

---

Edit, as suggested by Some programmer dude, created one thread per output stream:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

void doReadOutput( boost::process::ipstream* str, std::ostream* out, const std::string& prefix, boost::mutex* mutex )
{
    std::string line;

    if ( std::getline( *str, line ) )
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( *mutex );
        *out << prefix << ": " << line << std::endl;
    }
}

void readOutput( boost::process::ipstream* str, std::ostream* out, std::string prefix, boost::mutex* mutex, std::atomic_bool* continueFlag )
{
    while ( *continueFlag )
    {
        doReadOutput( str, out, prefix, mutex );
        boost::thread::yield();
    }

    // get last outputs that may remain in buffers
    doReadOutput( str, out, prefix, mutex );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if ( argc == 1 )
    {
        // run this same program with "foo" as parameter, to enter "else" statement below from a different process
        try
        {
            boost::process::ipstream is_stream, err_stream;

            std::stringstream merged_output;
            std::atomic_bool continueFlag = true;

            boost::process::child child( argv[0],
                                         std::vector<std::string>{ "foo" },
                                         boost::process::std_out > is_stream,
                                         boost::process::std_err > err_stream );

            boost::mutex mutex;
            boost::thread thrdis( boost::bind( readOutput, &is_stream, &merged_output, "cout", &mutex, &continueFlag ) );
            boost::thread thrderr( boost::bind( readOutput, &err_stream, &merged_output, "cerr", &mutex, &continueFlag ) );

            child.wait();

            continueFlag = false;

            thrdis.join();
            thrderr.join();

            std::cout << "Program output was:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << merged_output.str();
        }
        catch ( const boost::process::process_error& err )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << err.code() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...)                                                                                                                                      // @NOCOVERAGE
        {                                                     
            std::cerr << "Unknown error" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // program invoked through boost::process by "if" statement above

        std::cerr << "Error1" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello World1" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error2" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error3" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error4" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error5" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello World2" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error6" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello World3" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then the output is:

```
Program output was:
cerr: Error1
cout: Hello World1
cerr: Error2
cout: Hello World2
cerr: Error3
cout: Hello World3
cerr: Error4
cerr: Error5
cerr: Error6
```

Still unexpected...

Comment: You have to think about the order in which you do things... Like you *always* first read from "cout" and from "cerr". You need some synchronization between the processes, so the parent process know what channel ("cout" or "cerr") to read from.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: But the process I run in a 3rd party program, I can't sync anything here. I would expect a boost::process syntax that would redirect both `boost::process::std_out` and `boost::process::std_err` to the same `ipstream` preserving the order, but I could not achieve that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: If I read `err` before `is` the output is different, but still not what's expected.

Comment: @jpo38 I suggest you use asio + process. There is this useful function `async_read_until` that will allow you to react on every line asynchronously. Because what you are doing right now won't work in any way. You just read stdout and stderr and expect them to be read in order they were written to. And you are using `boost::process` not in the way it is meant to be used

Comment: @bartop: Could you please provide an example? I tried to call `async_read_unitl` with a `boost::process::ipstream` object but it does not work as it does not have a `async_read_some` function available...

Comment: A possible work-around might be to have two threads, one for each stream.

Comment: That's what I had in my code before I created the MCVE. But that does not guarantee the order to be preserved....with and without threads, it gets messed up.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Just updated my question with the piece of code using one thread per stream and the output, which remains unexpected.

Comment: Two separate file handles are not synchronized in any way. The best way to simulate it that I've seen is to do the output one line at a time. That way instead of 8,000 bytes of stdout, then 8,000 bytes of stderr you get alternating output lines of stdout, stderr, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You will need non-blocking IO. The supported way in the library is by using asynchronous pipes.

You would run a loop for both stderr/stdout doing

- async_read into a buffer until you get a full line or more
- copy the line from input buffer to the output buffer as soon as it became available

Because you'll end up having twice very much the same loop over pipe/buffer state, it makes sense to encapsulate it into a type, e.g.

```
    struct IoPump {
        IoPump(io_context& io, std::string& merged) : _pipe(io), _merged(merged) {}

        boost::asio::streambuf _buf;
        bp::async_pipe         _pipe;
        std::string&           _merged;

        void do_loop();
    };

    io_context io;

    std::string merged;
    IoPump outp{io, merged}, errp{io, merged};

    bp::child child(program, std::vector<std::string> { "foo" },
        bp::std_out > outp._pipe, bp::std_err > errp._pipe);

    outp.do_loop(); // prime the pump
    errp.do_loop(); // prime the pump
    io.run();
```

That's all. Well, except of course, what `IoPump::do_loop()` actually does:

```
void do_loop() {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(_pipe, _buf, "\n",
        [this, out = boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(_merged)](
            error_code ec, size_t xfer) mutable {
            if (!ec) {
                out.commit(buffer_copy(
                    out.prepare(xfer), _buf.data(), xfer));
                _buf.consume(xfer);

                do_loop(); // chain
            } else {
                std::cerr << "IoPump: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            }
        });
}
```

Note that

- your main application is completely single-threaded
- meaning that async completion handlers never run concurrently
- meaning that it is safe to just access the `std::string merged;` output buffer directly without worrying about synchronization

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bef55b502692976)**

```
static void main_program(char const* program);
static void child_program();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 1)
        main_program(argv[0]);
    else
        child_program();
}

#include <iostream>
static void child_program() {
    std::cerr << "Error1"       << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World1" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Error2"       << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Error3"       << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Error4"       << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Error5"       << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World2" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Error6"       << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World3" << std::endl;
}

#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

static void main_program(char const* program) {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    try {
        using boost::system::error_code;
        using boost::asio::io_context;

        struct IoPump {
            IoPump(io_context& io, std::string& merged) : _pipe(io), _merged(merged) {}

            boost::asio::streambuf _buf;
            bp::async_pipe         _pipe;
            std::string&           _merged;

            void do_loop() {
                boost::asio::async_read_until(_pipe, _buf, "\n",
                    [this, out = boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(_merged)](
                        error_code ec, size_t xfer) mutable {
                        if (!ec) {
                            out.commit(buffer_copy(
                                out.prepare(xfer), _buf.data(), xfer));
                            _buf.consume(xfer);

                            do_loop(); // chain
                        } else {
                            std::cerr << "IoPump: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                        }
                    });
            }
        };

        io_context io;

        std::string merged;
        IoPump outp{io, merged}, errp{io, merged};

        bp::child child(program, std::vector<std::string> { "foo" },
            bp::std_out > outp._pipe, bp::std_err > errp._pipe);

        outp.do_loop(); // prime the pump
        errp.do_loop(); // prime the pump
        io.run();

        std::cout << "Program output was:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << merged;
    } catch (const bp::process_error& err) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << err.code().message() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) { // @NOCOVERAGE
        std::cerr << "Unknown error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
IoPump: End of file
IoPump: End of file
```

And standard output:

```
Program output was:
Error1
Error2
Hello World1
Error3
Hello World2
Error4
Hello World3
Error5
Error6
```

### Other Examples

I've got many examples on this site already. Just look for [`async_pipe`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20async_pipe)

### Thinking Out Of The Box

You could simply redirect stderr into stdout at the descriptor level and be done! E.g.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7d08deb46798baf)**

```
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    std::future<std::string> merged;

    bp::child child(program, std::vector<std::string> { "foo" },
        bp::std_out > merged, bp::posix::fd.bind(2, 1), io);

    io.run();

    std::cout << "Program output was:" << std::quoted(merged.get()) << "\n";
```

Or with a line-wise reading loop:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a665dd78b1839c80)**

```
    bp::ipstream merged;

    bp::child child(program, std::vector<std::string> { "foo" },
        bp::std_out > merged, bp::posix::fd.bind(2, 1));

    child.wait();

    std::cout << "Program output was:" << std::endl;
    for (std::string line; getline(merged, line);)
        std::cout << "merged: " << std::quoted(line) << "\n";
```

Printing

```
Program output was:
merged: "Error1"
merged: "Hello World1"
merged: "Error2"
merged: "Error3"
merged: "Error4"
merged: "Error5"
merged: "Hello World2"
merged: "Error6"
merged: "Hello World3"
```

Comment: Thanks sehe. The code looks good, but your program still does not produce the expected output. For instance `Error2` should be printed after `Hello World1`...

Comment: I suspect is has more to do with Coliru than the code. Interesting, but try it for yourself. I cannot reproduce the Coliru result. [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IOXRytWiaRAm2MqF) and others concur

Comment: Just tested the code using Visual Studio 2019. I get a different output than Coliru, but still not what's expected. I see `Hello World1, Error1, Hello World2, Error2, Hello World3, Error3, Error4, Error5, Error6` while expecting `Error1, Hello World1, Error2, Error3, Error4, Error5, Hello World2, Error6, Hello World3`.

Comment: Ah. I see. The problem is - as I feared - that the `read_until` call can read multiple lines at once, but because I tried to hide complexity by "just leaving the extra data in the buffer for next iteration" we get the false ordering (because the other completion handler comes first). So, you **do** need to manually check for multiple lines in one completion

Comment: Then how would that affect the code you posted? Would adding a yield within the loop function to let the other wake up help?

Comment: There are no threads. How would a yield help? Also, if anything you want to **prevent** the other party from "going first" - the opposite of yield. However, I don't current;y have time to test alternatives.

Comment: OK, I see, it's true it's completely single thread. However, it does not solve my issue that is specifically the output ordering....

Comment: I believe you mentioned this on occasion :) However, I just realized. I may not have the ready answer, but we never - in good [SO] style - stopped to question the premise. Instead of trying to merge two async streams we could have a single one to begin with: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a665dd78b1839c80. In fact, you don't even need the pipe or the streambuffer any more. Just put it in a string or vector directly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7d08deb46798baf

Comment: That's really great, it's now synchronized. However, one last thing is missing ;-). I need to know what comes from `cout` and what comes from `cerr`. See in my question, what comes from `cerr` is prefixed `cerr:` and what comes from `cout` is prefixed `cout:`. With your edit solution, everything is prefixed `merged:`. If you have an idea...that would make your answer just perfect ;-)

Comment: Arg. The edit crossed with my work on the answer. Back to square one. Godspeed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229414/discussion-between-sehe-and-jpo38).

Comment: Aaarrrgh - I was so hoping you managed to get this working. I've the same sort of issue; my child is created using `(bp::stdout & bp::stderr) > pipe_` where `pipe_` is an `async_pipe`, and I use `async_read_some` to read from it. I see large blocks of `cerr` output then large blocks of `cout` output, but order is not preserved between the two.